# WSL2 install - plutus fails to build, unable to open db file in 'nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite'

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, nix

I'm attempting to finish the setup for plutus pioneers cohort3 on wsl2 (Windows 10) with Ubunutu 20.04. When I run the command:

`nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core.components.library`

I get:

`error: executing SQLite statement 'pragma synchronous = normal': unable to open database file (in '/nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite')`

I have already created /etc/nix/nix.conf to configure nix with the IOHK binary cache. I also checked and there is no var folder within the nix directory. Did I fail to create a db along the way or is something else amiss?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the permissions on your /nix directory.

If you run this command you should be able to move forward:

```
chmod 775 /nix
```

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: add code in-line with `enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday and I found that shutting down the distro and restarting it after installing nix worked to fix this issue, it may work for you as well.

- Exit out of the ubuntu distro
- In a windows terminal (powershell or whatever) use `wsl -l -v` to see the running distros
- Then use `wsl --terminate <DistributionName>` to stop the distro
- Then use `wsl --distribution <DistributionName>` to start the distro again
- Now you can try to build again.

Here's where I found the wsl commands -
https://winaero.com/terminate-running-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10/

[image]

On another note you should be using the plutus-apps repo not the plutus repo.
Here's a link to a doc from another pioneer who setup the environemnt with WSL that may help you -
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mLyuGmCvZLqFotpVElbhYR5Q6PUatGxSeGuulJ1izJA/edit

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

deleting the /nix/var directory

and then running

nix build -f default.nix docs.site --extra-experimental-features nix-command

fixed the

error: executing SQLite statement 'pragma synchronous = normal': unable to open database file (in '/nix/var/nix/db/db.sqlite')

error for me.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

I had success by uninstalling/removing Nix, and then installing it again

#### Uninstalling:

1. remove the `. "$HOME/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh"` line in
   your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`
2. `rm -rf $HOME/{.nix-channels,.nix-defexpr,.nix-profile,.config/nixpkgs}`
3. `sudo rm -rf /nix`

#### Reinstalling:

1. `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --no-daemon`
2. `. $HOME/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`